# Стили в php коде

Tags: php

Всем привет, мне надо сделать стили в php коде в **echo ' ';** 
Пробывал сделать

```
echo '' "<div style="color: #000000;">" . $data['name'] . "</div>" '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'] ."\r\n";
```

не работает, выдает только ошибку. Помогите поставить стиль в строке **23**
в этом коде:

```
echo '' . $data['name'] .  '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'] ."\r\n";
```

Код:

```
<?php
    // определяем начальные данные
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'название таблицы';
    $db_username = 'пользователь';
    $db_password = 'пароль';
    $db_table_to_show = 'название таблицы';

    // соединяемся с сервером базы данных
    $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
        or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

    // подключаемся к базе данных
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
        or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

    // выбираем все значения из таблицы "chat"
    $qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . $db_table_to_show)
        or die(mysql_error());

   // выводим сообщения в чат 
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
        echo '' . $data['name'] .  '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'] ."\r\n";
    }

    // закрываем соединение с сервером  базы данных
    mysql_close($connect_to_db); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Не забывайте, что текст ошибок дан для того, что бы его читать и определять причину ее возникновения. Поэтому ее тоже надо прикладывать к вопросу.

2) Спец. символы надо экранировать обратной чертой "\":

```
echo "<div style = \"color: #000000;\" >" . $data['name'] . "</div>" . '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'] ."\r\n";
```

Comment: Не правильно расставлены ковычки. Теперь у меня показывает в чате вместе с кодом. http://prntscr.com/2ifgie даже цвет не изменился (я его сменил на #0582C5)

Comment: Это <textarea>? Если да, то он не поддерживает включение тегов(они отображаются как текст) и таким образом вы не сможете выделить нужное.

Comment: Обычно для чатов использующих визуальные оформления делают div-контейнер. Соответственно все сообщения внутри тоже оформляются в тег  div. То есть вместо textarea делается <div></div> с нужными стилями(высота, ширина и т.д.) и вывод немного меняется: 
echo "<div><span style = \"color: #000000;\" >" . $data['name'] . "</span>" . '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'] ."<br /><div>";

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать этот контейнер. Нужно просто поле и чтоб можно было передвигать вверх и вниз.
Я не стал мучится с чатом, решил сделать простой, отправка сообщения в базу и вывод в <textarea>

Comment: Все довольно просто, вместо textarea делаете как в примере <div id="chat> со стилями: http://jsfiddle.net/DM6m6/ и в php немного меняете вывод как я написал выше: echo "<div><span style = \"color: #000000;\" >" . $data['name'] . "</span>" . '->' . $data['recipient'] . ':' . $data['mess'] ."<br /></div>";

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: А вот этого уже подсказать не могу, т.к. CSS я знаю только на уровне CSS2.

Comment: Ну все равно спасибо большое!

Comment: По поводу кастомизации скроллбара http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/169359/
http://habrahabr.ru/post/177399/